# how to disable the save button 

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have month drop down and the save button , i want to disable the save button if the value from the month drop down is selected as previous month in asp.net webpage

Comment: why not prevent showing previous months in the dropdown in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You should use javascript for this.
Use this function on onchange="checkdate()" of your drop down
you can also set it from code behind file. 
write  this in `Page_Load` function of your page...

```
 ddlMonths.Attributes.Add("onchange", "checkdate()");
```

Suppose that ddlMonths is your dropdown Id

```
function checkdate()// to check Month
{
    var ddlMonths = document.getElementById('<%=ddlMonths.ClientID %>');
    var btnSave =document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>');
    var lCurrentMonth = (new Date()).getMonth();

     if(ddlMonths.options[ddlMonths.selectedIndex].value < lCurrentMonth) 
          btnSave.disabled= true;
     else
         btnSave.disabled= false;
}
```

will give you the 1 less then month number starting from zero suppose that you give values to your MOnths in list starting from 0 to 11   or you can set it accordingly,  you can add 1 into Months if you start from 1-12

Answer (score 1):

If it's a regular dropdown with only one option to select, the onchange-function could be shortend

```
function checkDate() {
    var doc = document;

    var btn = doc.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>');
    var slc = doc.getElementById('<%=ddlMonths.ClientID %>');

    btn.disabled = (slc.selectedIndex < (new Date()).getMonth());
}
```